# MongoDB (With Spring data) - Archiving

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, archive

I am using mongo in my spring web application.

I have one document that is being constantly updated and populated with data.

I have a couple of questions:

1) If the document is indexed, and is being populated very rapidly, is it likely for the performance of my web app to be degraded over time? (My updates \ fetches are mostly done "byId" if that is relevant)

2) If the answer to question 1 is "yes" - How can I implement an archiving method for my huge collection? I would like to keep data for the last 2 months in that collection, and the other data should be archived. is that possible \ supported by spring\mongo?

3) In what way should i keep my archive? should it be a simple file? a different database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not mixing the meaning of `document` and `collection` in your question. Do you have just ONE document inside your collection that you update?

to 1) if you insert a new document into a collection with an Index (and the new document contains the indexed key) this operation gets slower if the collection grows because the Index must be updated and maybe documents need to be shifted in the storage format. If you insert (very) more often into your collection than you search in it you could consider to remove the index to speed up the insert (but slow down the search). You should performance test both solutions on a demo data set before making a fast decission.

to 2) I don't know if it is supported by spring. But you can use `mongoexport` to backup a single collection. Have a look at my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23611529/1515052).

```
mongoexport -d databasename -c collectionname -o savefilename.json
```

to 3) your exported collection will be a UTF-8 Text-file in JSON format. One line for each document inside the collection. After exporting you could `zip` the file to shrink the memory used.